# Return only selected value of checked input

Tags: reactjs

I need to display only the selected value of an option.  AT the moment I can mark the input with checked, but this is not that helpful
**checked={this.isOptionSelected(i)}**

I just need to display the checked value and no other.  I'm not sure if I would need to do an If statement or perhaps something a bit cleaner?

The markup

```
const getSelectedFromProps = props => {
return props.options.findIndex(x => x.value === props.value);
};

class TEST extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

static getDerivedStateFromProps(props) {       
    return {
        selected: getSelectedFromProps(props)
    };TEST
}

isOptionSelected(index) {
    return this.state.selected === index;
}

renderOptions() {
    return this.props.options.map((option, i) => (
        <div className="text-input">
            <input
                type='TextInput'
                checked={this.isOptionSelected(i)}
                value={option.label}
                ref={i === 0 ? this.props.inputRef : null}
            />
        </div>
    ));
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.renderOptions()}
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. What do you mean by "display the checked value and no other"?

Comment: I get back all of the options, and can see which one has been marked as checked, e.g.
<input type="TextInput"  value="A" checked>
<input type="TextInput"  value="B">
<input type="TextInput"  value="C">
but I only want to bring back A

Comment: ... So filter or don't return all of them? If just wrap with an `if` like you stated?

Comment: I guess I need to put if {this.isOptionSelected(i)} is true but not sure where this would go